# C++ Program miscalculation

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Variables
static float fAssignment, sAssignment, tAssignment, foAssignment, midAssignment, finalAssignment, secAssignment, Total;

// Function to collect the results
float Collector()
{
    printf("Enter the score for the first assignment: ");
        cin >> fAssignment;
    printf("Enter the score for the second assignment: ");
        cin >> sAssignment; 
    printf("Enter the score for the third assignment: ");
        cin >> tAssignment;
    printf("Enter the score for the fourth assignment: ");
        cin >> foAssignment;
    printf("Enter the score for the midterm: ");
        cin >> midAssignment;
    printf("Enter the score for the final: ");
        cin >> finalAssignment;
    printf("Enter the score for the section grade: ");
        cin >> secAssignment;
    return fAssignment, sAssignment, tAssignment, foAssignment, midAssignment, finalAssignment, secAssignment;
}

// Function to calculate the final grade/score
float Calculator()
{
    static float Average = ((fAssignment + sAssignment + tAssignment + foAssignment) / 4) * 0.4f;
    midAssignment * 0.15f;
    finalAssignment * 0.35f;
    secAssignment * 0.1f;
    Total = (Average + midAssignment + finalAssignment + secAssignment);
    return Total;
}


int main() 
{
    Collector();
    Calculator();
    printf("Your score is: ");
    cout << Total << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**These are the instructions along with the correct result at the bottom**

Write a program that will compute your final grade for a programming course you are taking. Here is the grading scheme:

```
Final grades will be based on the following:
40% Assignments   15% Midterm Examination
35% Final Examination
10% Class Participation Grade
```

Your program should ask the user for the four assignment scores, the midterm, final and section grades. Then, the final score is calculated and printed. To do the calculations, you average the four assignment scores together and then multiply it by 0.4 (40%). You then multiply the midterm score by 0.15, the final by 0.35 and the participation grade by 0.1. Then you add all the results of these multiplications together.

Use functions wherever you can in this program. You can create a function to get the input by passing in as a parameter the string to be displayed in an explanatory cout. Here is an example run:

```
Enter the score for the first assignment. 75
Enter the score for the second assignment. 85
Enter the score for the third assignment. 82
Enter the score for the fourth assignment. 94
Enter the score for the midterm. 81
Enter the score for the final. 89
Enter the score for the section grade. 100
The final grade is: 86.9
```

**But instead I get this result when I compile and run:**

```
Enter the score for the first assignment: 75
Enter the score for the second assignment: 85
Enter the score for the third assignment: 82
Enter the score for the fourth assignment: 94
Enter the score for the midterm: 81
Enter the score for the final: 89
Enter the score for the section grade: 100
Your score is: 303.6
```

**I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Community.**

Comment: Enable compiler warnings; that should give you a clue.

Comment: Did you debug your program at all (either with print statements, or better yet with a debugger by stepping through it) ?

Comment: `return fAssignment, sAssignment, tAssignment, foAssignment, midAssignment, finalAssignment, secAssignment;` 
You can only return one value from a function, there is no effect of all the other variables after comma.

Comment: "Write a program that will compute your final grade for a programming course you are taking": `int main(){return 100;}`

Comment: Don't cross the streams.  Use `cout` with `cin` and `printf` with `fscanf`.

Comment: I took all of your suggestions and critisism in account. Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines are not correct

```
midAssignment * 0.15f;
finalAssignment * 0.35f;
secAssignment * 0.1f;
```

You need to use `*=` to modify these variables

```
midAssignment *= 0.15f;
finalAssignment *= 0.35f;
secAssignment *= 0.1f;
```

The first method calculates some temporary `float`, then immediately throws it away since it isn't assigned to anything. In fact, the compiler probably just throws that whole line away.

Comment: I actually got these warning before, but I ignored them because I couldn't quite graps what it was trying to tell me.  warning C4552: '*' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect